# VBA in Excel: writing cell value to a column if it doesn't already exist there

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so I have a table of names in one column and corresponding numbers in another.  Most names appear more than once and each time with a different number.  The table is likely to be added to in the future.  I'm trying to write a VBA macro that will output each name once and the total sum of the numbers attached to them on a separate sheet.  I haven't used VBA in like 8 months and I'm really rusty.  Suggestions?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. I'd suggest recording a macro which copies the data into a new sheet / range, remove the duplicates and adds a `SUMIF` column to the next available column. From there, you should be able to work out the ranges etc. to include in the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember to add the reference  microsoft scripting runtime, i believe. u would need to use dictionary here.

```
Sub test()

    Dim var As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    Dim dico As Dictionary

    Set dico = New Dictionary
    For Each var In rng.Cells
        if dico.Exists(var.value) Then
             dico(var.value) = dico(var.value) + var.offset(0,1).value
        else
             dico.Add var.value, var.offset(0,1).value
        end if
    Next var

    Set rng = Range("C1")
    Dim i as double
    i = 0
    For Each var In dico.keys
        rng.offset(i).value = var
        rng.offset(i,1).value = dico(var)
    Next var

End sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a dictionary function.  Been using more python recently.